# mac os x urwid AttributeError: 'SelectableIcon' object has no attribute '_SelectableIcon__super'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, urwid

I am quite new to python an urwid. I found a seemingly OS X specific problem with urwid 1.3.0: 
I run Mac OS X 10.9.5 an have the by default installed python 2.7.5 and a manually installed python 3.4.2.
I have made no changes to the original code an tried the following:

I copied as instructed (https://github.com/wardi/urwid/wiki/Installation-instructions) the urwid folder from the package (urwid-1.3.0.tar.gz) into its examples folder to make urwid available for python and being able to test the examples. I got always the same error when executing e.g:

```
python bigtext.py
python3 bigtext.py
```

I also tried this with the very first tutorial from the urwid site

```
# hellotest.py
import urwid

txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')
loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
loop.run()
```

All examples, just like the short one above, produce the following Error:

```
mymac:examples me$ python3 hellotest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hellotest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urwid
  File "myfolder/urwid-1.3.0/examples/urwid/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from urwid.wimp import (SelectableIcon, CheckBoxError, CheckBox, RadioButton,
  File "myfolder/urwid-1.3.0/examples/urwid/wimp.py", line 99, in <module>
    class CheckBox(WidgetWrap):
  File "myfolder/urwid-1.3.0/examples/urwid/wimp.py", line 104, in CheckBox
    True: SelectableIcon("[X]"),
  File "myfolder/urwid-1.3.0/examples/urwid/wimp.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.__super.__init__(text)
AttributeError: 'SelectableIcon' object has no attribute '_SelectableIcon__super'
```

This Error does not occur when i try this on a fresh Raspbian (Debian) on a Raspberry Pi. 
So it seems to me this is a OS specific problem.

Can someone find why this behaviour occurs on OS X, or does it even happen on other systems too? And does someone have an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance